# How to split a nested list into a smaller nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a nested list as my input (and the nested list is always square. ie. same number of rows as columns). I want to break this list up into another nested list of which the elements are just 2x2 "parts" of the original list.

For example, if my input was

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[5,6,7,8],
[9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16]]
```

my output should be 
`[[1,2,5,6], [3,4,7,8], [9,10,13,14], [11,12,15,16]]`

Another example:
input:

```
[[1,2,3],
[5,6,7],
[9,10,11],
```

output:
`[[1,2,5,6],[3,7],[9,10],[11]]`

I've tried making a nested for loop that goes through the first two columns and rows and makes that into a list and then appends that to another list and then repeats the process, but I get an index out of bounds exception error

This is what I've done so far

```
def get_2_by_2(map: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    i = 0
    j = 0
    lst_2d = []
    lst = []

    for row in range(i, min(i+2, len(map))):
        for column in range(j, min(j+2, len(map))):
            print(row,column)
            lst.append(map[row][column])  
    lst_2d.append(lst)
    return lst_2d
```

basically this one only returns the first 2x2. I attempted using a while loop on the outside and incrementing the values of i and j and making my while loop dependent on one of them. that resulted in an index out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the rows and columns in a step of 2, and slice the list of lists accordingly:

```
def get_2_by_2(matrix):
    output = []
    for row in range(0, len(matrix), 2):
        for col in range(0, len(matrix[0]), 2):
            output.append([i for r in matrix[row: row + 2] for i in r[col: col + 2]])
    return output
```

or with a nested list comprehension:

```
def get_2_by_2(matrix):
    return [
        [i for r in matrix[row: row + 2]
        for i in r[col: col + 2]] for col in range(0, len(matrix[0]), 2)
    ]
```

so that given:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7, 8],
     [9, 10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

`get_2_by_2(m)` returns:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8], [9, 10, 13, 14], [11, 12, 15, 16]]
```

and that given:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [5, 6, 7],
     [9, 10, 11]]
```

`get_2_by_2(m)` returns:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 7], [9, 10], [11]]
```